# Netty 4 multithreaded DefaultEventExecutorGroup

Tags: multithreading, networking, netty

I started a netty4 nio server with  multiple business threads for handling long-term businesses
like below

```
public void start(int listenPort, final ExecutorService ignore)
        throws Exception {
            ...
    bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    ioGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    businessGroup = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(businessThreads);

    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    b.group(bossGroup, ioGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, 
                         Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty(
                                 "nfs.rpc.tcp.nodelay", "true")))
            .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, 
                         Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty(
                                 "nfs.rpc.tcp.reuseaddress", "true")))
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch)
                        throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast("decoder",
                            new Netty4ProtocolDecoder());
                    ch.pipeline().addLast("encoder",
                            new Netty4ProtocolEncoder());
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(businessGroup, "handler",
                            new Netty4ServerHandler());
                }
            });

    b.bind(listenPort).sync();
    LOGGER.warn("Server started,listen at: " + listenPort + ", businessThreads is " + businessThreads);
}
```

I found that there was only one thread working when  the server accepted one connection. 
How can I bootstrap a server that can start multiple business threads for only one connection?

Thanks,
Mins

Answer (score 2):

Netty will always use the same thread for one connection. It's by design. If you would like to change this you may be able to implement a custom EventExecutorGroup and pass it in when adding your ChannelHandler to the ChannelPipeline.

Be aware this may result in messed up order of packets.